# Pandas "replace" method not working to replace a dot (.) character

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote 2 very similar codes to replace characters (?, .) to nan values in Python. Unfortunately one of them worked perfectly but other did not.  Here are the codes

```
df_train['SES'].replace('?',np.nan, inplace= True)
```

That worked perfectly, but

```
df_train['CLUSTER_CODE'].replace('.', np.nan, inplace= True)
```

this one is very similar code to above, but did not work. Any advice please as i'm very new to python and trying to learn.

Comment: Are you sure here are `'.'` values in he second column? can you print the value of `len(df_train[df_train['CLUSTER_CODE']=='.'])`?

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data as text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking notice. and I am sure in the column it is as .

Comment: @Alireza, here i'm pasting all the unique numbers of the column just to make sence

Comment: 51    457
14    451
 .    446
41    427
16    383

Comment: It worked for me.
I used `pd.DataFrame(['1', '2', '.', '3']).replace('.', np.nan)inplace=True)`. What error are you getting?

Comment: Here is a crazy idea! instead of writing the dot using your keyboard in your python code, copy-paste the value from your table directly... I suggest this because there are multiple chars rendered as dot, but slightly different (in code). I had the same problem once.

Comment: Thanks, this crazy idea actually worked, I did copy-paste the value from the table directly and it appeared to be working. thank you much @ Alireza